# Fastest real time decompression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression

I'm looking for an algorithm to decompress chunks of data (1k-30k) in real time with minimal overhead. Compression should preferably be fast but isn't as important as decompression speed.

From what I could gather LZO1X would be the fastest one. Have I missed anything? Ideally the algorithm is not under GPL.

Comment: Decompression of what? Files? Streams? IP packets? Video? What encoding?

Comment: Wouldn't no compression be the fastest compression?

Comment: @JensSchauder: Definitely no, If decompression exceeds RAM speed (decompressing into L2/L3 cache for example), you can achieve more speed by compression than without it. When using disk, or network your compression advantage can be even bigger.

Answer (score 7):

[lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4) is what you're looking for here.

> LZ4 is lossless compression algorithm, providing compression speed at
>   400 MB/s per core, scalable with multi-cores CPU. It features an
>   extremely fast decoder, with speed in multiple GB/s per core,
>   typically reaching RAM speed limits on multi-core systems.

Answer (score 4):

Try Google's [Snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/).

> Snappy is a compression/decompression library. It does not aim for maximum compression, or compatibility with any other compression library; instead, it aims for very high speeds and reasonable compression. For instance, compared to the fastest mode of zlib, Snappy is an order of magnitude faster for most inputs, but the resulting compressed files are anywhere from 20% to 100% bigger. On a single core of a Core i7 processor in 64-bit mode, Snappy compresses at about 250 MB/sec or more and decompresses at about 500 MB/sec or more.

Comment: Yuku, we observe decompression speed of 10-12Mb/sec (vs 500Mb/s claimed on wiki) running `hadoop -text ${snappy_compressed_file}`. Hadoop native libs are installed (including snappy native). Any thoughts? Our CPU Info (Amazon EMR) Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz

Comment: My own app running on 1.2 Ghz ARMv7 processor decompresses 5MB data in 100ms. Did you decompress from memory or there are I/O overhead?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Yuku. There is I/O involved, however, the overhead is rather negligible compared to decompression hit. Here is the same question with a bit more details on snappy google group: http://goo.gl/LBapFc

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot use GPL licensed code your choice is clear - [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/). Very permissive license, fast compression, fair compression ratio, very fast decompression, works everywhere and ported to every sane language.

Comment: This paper: http://www.kkant.net/papers/lzo_results.pdf claims 20x decompression speed advantage of LZO versus zlib (of course with worsened compressibility performance).

Comment: Yeah, zlib is good at many things, but it's not the best at decompression speeds. I had something like QuickLZ in mind.

Comment: As a zlib co-author and the zlib maintainer, I can say that this is not a good answer to this question. There are much faster decompressors, if you allow for less effective compression.