# Fast decompression algorithms

Tags: performance, algorithm, compression

I'm looking for compression/deompression algorithms that can give decent compression 2-4x on regular english text and yet I can decompress this data almost as fast as I can get it out of main memory (~10Gbps). Whats the current state of the art in terms of fast decompression algorithms (perhaps vectorized code that uses multiple cores)

In particular, I'm looking at this paper [Fast Integer compression using SIMD instructions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~rgemulla/publications/schlegel10compression.pdf&ei=9WXjT6SdCaKe2QXM8NnNCA&usg=AFQjCNHgwdqc_ocCxHjrcjNwQo14ke7ALQ&sig2=yoKMbAIxlRCmlFaWB1AyTA)
and wondering if similar algorithms have been used in any system.

Comment: They say LZ4 is pretty fast (saturates RAM speed on multicore systems).

Comment: This is a discussion question, and isn't appropriate here. It's also a duplicate of many prior posts (for instance, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479098/fastest-real-time-decompression-algorithm?rq=1)). [SO isn't a discussion site or search  page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479098/fastest-real-time-decompression-algorithm?rq=1).

Comment: I thought that the link under "SO isn't a discussion site or search page" would provide an explanation of what SO _is_ for.  However it links to the same place as the "this one" link.

Answer (score 19):

Look at [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) and [lz4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/).  Try them on your data and see how they perform.

Answer (score 0):

A golomb code can be good like a huffman and is very simple and fast.

Answer (score -3):

[BWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BWT) + [entropy coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_coding) (for instance [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)) is quite fast (compexity O(n)) but needs two pass.

Comment: BWT is extremely slow compared to the memory speeds quoted in the original question.  Much, much faster algorithms, such as LZO and lz4 should be considered.  gzip has much faster decompression than BWT (e.g. bzip2), but is still not fast enough to meet the needs outlined here.

Comment: inverse-BWT is not fast at all, and costs lots of memory.